# How to block editing per column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I created an application with login. The password is hashed with bcrypt, and so far everything is fine. But today I asked myself, what if the database is hacked, and the hash code in the password column is changed? That's why I would like to know if in POSTGRESQL there is some type of action that completely blocks the administrator from editing passwords, keeping password changes only for users and through the website itself.

Comment: You can never keep a superuser from doing anything they want.

Comment: The administrator is by definition a trusted person. It should have signed an agreement with legal implications if they disclose, change, delete, alter, or doctor the data any shape or form.